# Wiring L14-20 Receptacle on generator to a 6-20 Plug

Tags: electrical, generator

Big question. On my pigtail, do I use 2 hot + ground and tape off the neutral?

Answer (score 2):

Correct.  The 6-20 plug has no neutral. It needs no neutral.

You don't even need to use /4 flexible cord**.  You can use /3, hot-hot-ground or hot-(taped white)-ground, and there won't be a neutral wire to connect.

---

** In flexible cord, grounds are counted in the number, unlike Romex/NM cable.